# Flex: Loading assets into externally loaded modules

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

So, I have Flex project that loads a Module using the ModuleManager - not the module loader.  The problem that I'm having is that to load an external asset (like a video or image) the path to load that asset has to be relative to the Module swf...not relative to the swf that loaded the module.

The question is - How can I load an asset into a loaded module using a path relative to the parent swf, not the module swf?

---

Arg!  So in digging through the SWFLoader Class I found this chunk of code in private function loadContent:

```
    // make relative paths relative to the SWF loading it, not the top-level SWF
    if (!(url.indexOf(":") > -1 || url.indexOf("/") == 0 || url.indexOf("\\") == 0))
    {
         var rootURL:String;
         if (SystemManagerGlobals.bootstrapLoaderInfoURL != null && SystemManagerGlobals.bootstrapLoaderInfoURL != "")
              rootURL = SystemManagerGlobals.bootstrapLoaderInfoURL;
         else if (root)
              rootURL = LoaderUtil.normalizeURL(root.loaderInfo);
         else if (systemManager)
              rootURL = LoaderUtil.normalizeURL(DisplayObject(systemManager).loaderInfo);

              if (rootURL)
              {
                   var lastIndex:int = Math.max(rootURL.lastIndexOf("\\"), rootURL.lastIndexOf("/"));
                    if (lastIndex != -1)
                         url = rootURL.substr(0, lastIndex + 1) + url;
               }
          }
}
```

So apparently, Adobe has gone through the extra effort to make images load in the actual swf and not the top level swf (with no flag to choose otherwise...), so I guess I should submit a feature request to have some sort of "load relative to swf" flag, edit the SWFLoader directly, or maybe I should have everything relative to the individual swf and not the top level...any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import `mx.core.Application` and then use [Application.application.url](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/Application.html#url) to get the path of the host application in your module and use that as the basis for building the URLs.

For help in dealing with URLs, see [the URLUtil class in the standard Flex libraries](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/utils/URLUtil.html) and [the URI class in the as3corelib project](http://as3corelib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/com/adobe/net/URI.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.url in the module and use this as a baseURL.

```
var urlParts:Array = this.url.split("/");
urlParts.pop();
baseURL = urlParts.join("/");
Alert.show(baseURL);
```

and use `{baseURL + "/location/file.ext"}` instead of `/location/file.ext`